# int.TryParse no funciona

Tags: c#

Tengo una variable llamada "telefono_destinatario", el dato de la variable es recibido desde un json enviado desde postman.
El problema que ocurre es que al enviar 9 caracteres numéricos la validación isNumeric si funciona, pero al enviar más de 9 caracteres numéricos el isNumeric los toma como si no fueran caracteres numéricos, a pesar de que yo solo envie números del 1 al 10 por ejemplo el int.TryParse toma el campo como si no fuera numérico

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para empezar.. UN TELEFONO NO ES UN NUMERO... luego de dicho eso, int.TryParse si lo toma, lo que pasa es que se llama int porque justamente solo acepta int. no otro valor.. y un valor de 10 digitos supera el maximo de int... IsNumeric esta dentro del espacio de visual basic.. no tendrias que usarlo, pero es valido.. ahora tiene el mismo problema que int... se fija si es convertible...

Comment: entonces.. la respuesta es, usa otro metodo para validar que sean numeros.. por ejemplo, partelo en pedacitos.. o usa una expresion regular...

Comment: Como ha dicho gbianchi, el rango de int va desde 2,147,483,648 a +2,147,483,648. prueba a cambiarle el tipo a float, double u otro que acepte numeros mas grandes

Comment: No es una solución recomendable. Aunque `float` y `double` permiten representar un gran rango de números con decimales, `float` codifica números reales de forma que 1 bit corresponde al signo, 8 al exponente y 23 a la precisión. Comparado con un `int`, tienes un cuarto menos de precisión, lo que significa que puedes almacenar menos dígitos. De la misma manera, `double` te permite almacenar menos dígitos que `long`.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pin em código que tienes

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaria primeramente comenzar por los [diferentes tipos de datos para números que nos propone C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) o su correspondiente tipo en .NET, donde puedes ver el rango y el tamaño , pero ademas tenemos uno especial llamado [BigInteger (System.Numerics.BigInteger)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger), que literalmente

> Use la estructura System.Numerics.BigInteger para representar un entero con signo sin límite superior ni inferior.

Te comento esto porque en tu caso, seguramente el numero que viene en la cadena que quieres "parsear" no cabe en un tipo de dato int (C#) (Int32 en NET). Por eso te devuelve "false", mira un ejemplo

Ejemplo
(lo puedes probar online https://dotnetfiddle.net/gOAnYm )

```
        var longNumberString = "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789";
    
    var isNumberA = int.TryParse(longNumberString, out _);
    Console.WriteLine($"isNumberA = {isNumberA}");
    
    var isNumberB = long.TryParse(longNumberString, out _);
    Console.WriteLine($"isNumberB = {isNumberB}");
    
    var isNumberC = UInt64.TryParse(longNumberString, out _);
    Console.WriteLine($"isNumberC = {isNumberC}");
    
    //Option 1: BigInteger.TryParse
    var isNumberD = BigInteger.TryParse(longNumberString, out _);
    Console.WriteLine($"isNumberD = {isNumberD}");
```

El resultado es

```
isNumberA = False
isNumberB = False
isNumberC = False
isNumberD = True
```

Como veras en números que ya sabremos que son "muy grandes" es conveniente utilizar [BigInteger.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tryparse?view=net-6.0) que es el unico que nos devuelve "True"

Tambien hay otras alternativas (por ejemplo con expresion regular, o recorriendo toda la cadena preguntando por IsDigit de cada caracter)

Ejemplo

```
    //Option 1: BigInteger.TryParse
    var isNumberD = BigInteger.TryParse(longNumberString, out _);
    Console.WriteLine($"isNumberD = {isNumberD}");
    
    Console.WriteLine();
    
    //Option 2: Regex
    var isNumber1 = Regex.IsMatch(longNumberString, @"^\d+$");
    Console.WriteLine($"isNumber1 = {isNumber1}");
    
    //Option 3: Linq > All with IsDigit method
    var isNumber2 = longNumberString.All(char.IsDigit);
    Console.WriteLine($"isNumber2 = {isNumber2}");
```

Asi que estas son tus alternativas. Dependiendo de la performance tendriamos que ver mas produndamente pero es otro tema. Ejemplo, para IsLetter hice unas pruebas

- [Verify is letter or digit (Benchmark in c#)](https://github.com/fernandezja/verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark) >
  https://github.com/fernandezja/verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Tipos de datos numericos en C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)
- [BigInteger (System.Numerics.BigInteger)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger)
- [BigInteger.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tryparse?view=net-6.0)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: me sirvió perfecto, con BigInteger y con la expresión regular, muchas gracias <3